# How to avoid namespace activerecord models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm using rails 3.2.3 with more than 100 models. The thing is that the directory app/models is too crowded. I organized the directory into several groups and add autoload_paths (for the new sub directories). I don't want my models to use namespace, because it would end up into several namespaces which is not good for development.
Let's say:

```
# app/models/listing.rb
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :communications
end

# app/models/listing/communication.rb
class Communication < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

In my rails console, it works for any models with absolute reference except in the activerecord associations. I cannot call Listing.first.communications. I see what it does it is trying to load Listing::Communication, and it failed out because the content of this file is Communication (without namespace).

```
LoadError: Expected /home/chamnap/my_app/app/models/listing/communication.rb to define Listing::Communication
```

Is there a way to group models into directory and use them without namespace? Or is there a way to preload all models so that Rails doesn't load model on the fly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a problem with models in subdirectories and associations in Rails 3. I also have stumbled upon this.

My solution was to point an explicit :class_name for every association to model in subdirectory, like

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :communications, :class_name => "::Communication"
end
```

Take notice of using "::" before model name -- it says to rails that there is no namespace for Communication model.

Comment: Ah, thanks alot. I check the activerecord, and I see how it loads the associations (using compute_type), but I forgot about this one. I went through some blogs, and it says it's a default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

```
# e.g. subscription/coupon defines ::Coupon, would would blow up with expected coupon.rb to define Subscription::Coupon
# to remove this:
# a: namespace the models
# b: move them to top-level
# c: add :class_name => "::Coupon" to all places where they are used as associations
ActiveRecord::Reflection::MacroReflection.class_eval do
  def class_name_with_top_level
    "::#{class_name_without_top_level}".sub("::::","::")
  end
  alias_method_chain :class_name, :top_level
end
```